# value of an object from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an object that looks like this

```
discount = {salesman: 0, supervisor: 0.02, manager: 0.05};
group_name = 'salesman';
```

I need to get the value of discount.group_name so if the group_name = 'salesman' I should get 0, if the group_name = manager I should get 0.05 and so on.

I tried to get it by doing

```
console.log(discount.group_name)
```

but it didn't work.

Please help me.

Comment: do this console.log(discount[group_name])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
console.log( discount[group_name] );
```

Look [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much I will accept this answer.